# Populating nodes based on condition in Receiver file

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt

I need to populate one segment based on  input values.the requirement like below

in the input payload we are getting below segment like

```
 <charac>
    <charactername>
     <charactervalue>
   </charac>
```

so the above segment may come multiple times but based on the few values only need to populate the segment for example,

```
      <charac>
    <charactername>print</charactername>
     <charactervalue>123</charactervalue>
   </charac>

   <charac>
    <charactername>comp</charactername>
     <charactervalue>1234</charactervalue>
   </charac>

   <charac>
    <charactername>pal</charactername>
     <charactervalue>1235</charactervalue>
   </charac>
```

so here only I need populate segment when charactername is equal to only **print** or **comp**

the receiver structure the segment is

```
  <e1edl1>
    <at>
     <rt>
     </e1edl1>
```

so the output should be like

```
   <e1edl1>
    <at>print</at>
     <rt>123</rt>
     </e1edl1>

     <e1edl1>
    <at>comp</at>
     <rt>1234</rt>
     </e1edl1>
```

I tried with below code

```
<ns0:if test="count(./charac)!=0">
 <ns0:for-each select="./charac">
 <e1edl1 SEGMENT="1">
 <at>
     <ns0:value-of select="charactername" /> 
    </at>
    <rt>
  <ns0:value-of select="charactervalue" /> 
    </rt>
   </e1edl1>
  </ns0:for-each>
 </ns0:if>
```

could you please help on this.

Regards,
Janardhan

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show any XSLT you have currently tried? Thank you!

Comment: sorry Tim,  I am new to this xslt code , I tried but the correct syntax I am not able to get.. I need your help on this.

Comment: I have added some code but based on condition I am not able to populate.

Comment: Thanks. However, your XSLT sample is trying to select `BatchChar` elements, but there are no such elements in your XML. Is your XML sample correct? (Also note that XML and XSLT are case sensitive, so `Charac` is not the same as `charac`).

Comment: sorry tim,I have corrected it. my xslt code will not work for the conditions it just taking the values whatever will come. I need the code how can we populate based on the condition as mentioned in my post.

Comment: Xml structure is still unclear: charac and charc don't match

Comment: yes, I have edited now.. please check

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//charac[charactername='print' or charactername='comp']" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="charac">
     <e1edl1>
         <at><xsl:value-of select="charactername" /></at>
         <rt><xsl:value-of select="charactervalue" /></rt>
     </e1edl1>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```